# How to re-promote a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook

I had a Facebook post that I promoted, and the promotion has run out. It was actually very successful and I want to promote the same post again. However, I see no such option anywhere on the post promotion menu. I also see nothing about this in the Facebook help section. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only promote a post on Facebook once. If you want to promote it again, you'll need to create a new post and promote that.

You can only publicise a recently made post. This is [usually up to three days](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2183567/4-Critical-Things-To-Know-About-Facebook-Promoted-Posts). If it's from a personal account, it's within the last six:

> #### [Why can't I promote a post?](http://www.facebook.com/help/416021091787548/)
>
> You can only promote posts you've shared recently, typically within the last 6 hours. Group posts and private messages are not eligible to be promoted.

When you run a promotion on a post it will run long enough as to make it unable to promote the same one again.

Comment: If anyone searches for this and finds this post, this was the best answer at the time, but Facebook does now allow re-promotion of posts.